# run script program in python

Tags: python, action, argparse, shutil

I have a little project in python to do. I have to parse 4 arguments in my program.
so the commands are:
-i (store the source_file) 
-d (store the destination_file)
-a (store the a folder named: i386, x64_86 or all )
-p (store the folder named: Linux, Windows or all)

The folder Linux has 2 folders in: i386 and x64_86; the folder has those 2 folderswindows too

My script has to copy the forders like i tell him, there are 9 combinations, for example:

Python exemple.py -i -d -a i386 p windows
So in this exemple i have to copy just the forder windows containing just the folder i386

to copy the files i use the shutil.copytree(source_file, destination, ignore=ignore_patterns(.....))

i manage to acces the input and the output( args.input, args.output) but for arch and platform i have to acces the coices and i dont know how.

Any idea please ?

```
pars = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='copy dirs script')
a1 = pars.add_argument("-i", "--input", required=True, nargs="?",
                       help="the source dirctory is /""X:/.......")
a2 = pars.add_argument("-o", "--output", required=True, nargs="?",
                       help="the destination dirctory is the curently working dirctory")
pars.add_argument("-a", "--arch", choices=["all", "i386", "x86_64"], required=True,
                       help="Targeted check architecture: 32b, 64b, All")
pars.add_argument("-p", "--platform", choices=["all", "windows", "linux"], required=True,
                       help="Targeted check platform: Windows, Linux, All")
```

Any idea please ?

Comment: Try to imagine reading this from the point of view of someone who does not live in your head and isn't familiar with your work.

Comment: Yeah, i thing you are right, i just changed it. i hope is good now

Comment: take a look at `glob` and `os.walk`, may get you started....

Comment: What do you mean by access the choices? It is still unclear what the problem is. You aren't showing how you run and then use the result of the parser...

Comment: So i have 2 big folders: Windows and Linux.
Each of them has these two i386 and x86_64 folders.
I have to copy what's in folders but after the command I give it. if I run the program like this:
Python example.py -i -d -a i386 p windows
Will only copy the i386 folder in the windows folder
if a much easier exeption would be:
Python example.py -i -d -a all p all
In this exe I will copy the i386 and x86_64 folders from windows but also from Linux
so there are 9 command combinations

Answer (score 0):

```
add_argument("-i", "--input", required=True, nargs="?")
```

works, but isn't the best.  Normally a flagged argument with '?' used with a `default` and `const` parameters.  If the flag isn't used, it gets the `default`.  If used without added string, it gets the `const`.  Otherwise it gets the string.

By using `required` you eliminate one of those alternatives.  But you didn't specify a `const`.  I'd drop the `nargs`.  Better yet drop the `required` and define a reasonable `default`.

I keep encouraging posters to do

```
args = pars.parse_args()
print(args)
```

to see what the parser gives you, before you stumble around trying to the Namespace.

```
args.arch
args.platform
```

will each have a string value the corresponds to one of their choices.

Commonly arguments like that will be used with:

```
if args.arch == 'all':
    ....
elif args.arch == "i386":
    ....
```

or

```
if args.arch in ['all', 'i386']:
    # do something with i386
elif     ....  in ['all', "x86_64"]:
    ....
```

The `if` logic just has to fit your needs.  The are alternative ways of using such values, such as a dictionary look up

```
adict[args.arch]
```

Once you have the values, `args.arch`, etc, you are done with `argparse`.  The rest is the same sort of program logic you need to handle alternatives.

Comment: thanks ! i will try, and i will post the result ! As you can see i'm at the beginning :)

Comment: I just made it work, but does not recognize the --arch and --platform argument, this is my parser: 

pars.add_argument('-a','--arch', action='store_const', const=['i386','x64_86'] , default='all',
     help="this will store the folder containing  the files specified for the architecture")

and this is the output i gave:
for exaple: python script.py -i -o -a i386 -p windows

script.py: error: unrecongnized arguments: i386 windows

Comment: the print is:

Namespace(arch='all', input=None, output=None, platform='all')

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from shutil import *
import argparse


var1 = ""
var2 = ""
source_file = ""
destination_file = ""

pars = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='copy dirs script', description="à copier MSRE localment:",
                               epilog="Comme ça on copie les repertoires")
pars.add_argument("-i", "--input", nargs="?", type = lambda s : s.lower(),
                       help="the source dirctory is /""X:/......")
pars.add_argument("-o", "--output", nargs="?", type = lambda s : s.lower(),
                       help="the destination dirctory is the curently working dirctory")
pars.add_argument("-a", "--arch", choices=("all", "i386", "x86_64"), type = lambda s : s.lower(),
                       help="Targeted check architecture: 32b, 64b, All")
pars.add_argument("-p", "--platform", choices=("all", "windows", "linux"), type = lambda s : s.lower(),
                       help="Targeted check platform: Windows, Linux, All")
args = pars.parse_args()

print(args)
print('\n')

if str(args.input) and str(args.output):
    source_file = "X:/asdasd/askkkkkkk"
    destination_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Bla/bla/bla")
else:
    print("wrog command !!! Please follow the help commands") 



if args.arch == 'all' and args.platform == 'all':
    var1 = ''
    var2 = ''
elif args.arch == 'all' and args.platform == 'linux':
    var1 = ''
    var2 = 'windows'
elif args.arch == 'all' and args.platform == 'windows':
    var1 = ''
    var2 = 'linux'
elif args.arch == 'i386' and args.platform == 'all':
    var1 = 'x86_64'
    var2 = ''
elif args.arch == 'i386' and args.platform == 'linux':
    var1 = 'x86_64'
    var2 = 'windows'
elif args.arch == 'i386' and args.platform == 'windows':
    var1 = 'x86_64'
    var2 = 'linux'
elif args.arch == 'x86_64' and args.platform == 'all':
    var1 = 'i386'
    var2 = ''
elif args.arch == 'x86_64' and args.platform == 'linux':
    var1 = 'i386'
    var2 = 'windows'    
elif args.arch == 'x86_64' and args.platform == 'windows':
    var1 = 'i386'
    var2 = 'linux'  
else:
    print("an error has occurred"+ pars.print_help())


ignoreP =ignore_patterns(
    "conf", "inc", "java", "VERSION", "*.ini", "*.ksh",
    "*.txt", var1, var2)

# print(str(ignoreP))

copytree(source_file, destination_file, ignore=ignoreP)
```